# Passing TableViewCellNumber to another view when clicked always null at first

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, uitableview

i have build a UIViewController will tableview, added the didSelectRowAtIndexPath to get the index of the row pressed and then set a global variable to hold the row number so as to use it in the next view controller

however when i click on the table view cell, it open the other activity and load content from the internet, however the row number is zero until the other view controller loads data and displays it ! the passed data is vital for selecting item from MYSQL

this is to get the row number and store in extern variable called catIDTemp

```
didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"categories %ld", (long)row);
    catIDTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)row];
}
```

when reading the catIDTemp from the other view controller like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSLog(@"valueeee %@", catIDTemp);

    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"loading items..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [indicator startAnimating];
    [alertView setValue:indicator forKey:@"accessoryView"];
    [alertView show];

    self.AllItemsTableView.delegate = self;
    self.AllItemsTableView.dataSource = self;

    feedItems = [[NSArray alloc] init];
    ConnModel = [[AllItemsConnectModel alloc] init];
    ConnModel.delegate = self;
    [ConnModel downloadItems];
}
```

it load data with catIDTemp as null !!!!!

also by using the nslog as shown above
it prints

```
2014-12-29 19:40:07.551 appname[1814:469443] valueeee (null)
2014-12-29 19:40:07.568 appname[1814:469443] categories 0
```

how come it prints the "valueeee" from the second view and then prints "catrgories" from the first View !

to move from the first view to the second, i pressed on the table cell "right mouse click" dragged it to the second view, released and set as "model"

i need to pass the variable catIDTemp before having the second view launch the mysql query !

I made a breakpoint and tested the code.

seems that is starts the secondViewController Before calling the didSelectRowAtIndexPath which is in the firstViewController !!! which make the catIDTemp always null at first !

how to set to the row number before opening the secondView ?

Comment: how and where did you create instance of second view controller?

Comment: i added ViewController from the UI Items and named it secondViewController then added a new file with subclass UIViewController named it SecondViewController and that created the .h file and the .m file , then linked those to the UIViewController.. is this what you mean ?

Comment: The reason that `catIDTemp` is null on your other view controller is because you're not giving it a value.  You assign `catIDTemp` a value when you tap on the UITableViewCell, but that is only for that view controller - you need to pass that variable on to the other view controller when you create that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make catIDTemp property in SecondViewController class

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *catIDTemp;
```

and pass the value in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    row = indexPath.row;
    NSLog(@"categories %ld", (long)row);

    SecondViewController *second = (SecondViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StoryBordIdentifier"];;

   second.catIDTemp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)row]; 


    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Remove seague from story board and change the code as shown above.

Comment: Thanks, Works like a charm, and i change the last line to this >>>>>>>> [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil]; <<<<<<< to improve the code for os 7+